# if the answer is 200N then why?? because if 200N then object wouldn't move at all

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

question is. using a horizontal force of 200 N , we intend to move a wooden cabinet across a floor at a constant velocity. what is the friction force that will be exerted on the cabinet?

Comment: alv karthik, it is an absolutely KEY physics concept that objects moving at constant velocity, including but not limited to zero velocity, experience no net force acting on them.  If a net force is acting on an object, it MUST accelerate.  As non-intuitive as these two concepts sound, you will not be able to effectively solve quite a few physics problems until you accept and internalize these concepts.

Answer (score 4):

If the cabinet is moving at constant velocity then the friction force must be equal and opposite to the applied horizontal force of $200$ N, so that the net horizontal force on the cabinet is zero.

We do not need to speculate on how the cabinet started moving to answer the question - but we can if we like. Maybe the applied force was originally greater than $200$ N in order to start it moving. Maybe the friction force was originally less than $200$ N. Maybe the cabinet has always been moving since the beginning of time ...